# Preventing memory leak on dynamically created DOM elements

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).on('mouseover','img.avatar',function(e) {
    
});

jQuery(document).on('mouseleave','img.avatar',function(e) {

});
```

I have a jQuery chat application that allows user to interact with other people's avatar in a 2d space. Every time the user hovers an avatar, there's a tooltip that appears over the avatar. However, these avatars are dynamically created object. How do you make sure that the event listeners don't cause a memory leak?

I do a remove here, but I am wondering how I can remove everything associated with the avatar including the event listeners. Do I even have to unbind the event listener if it's a dynamic event listener using "on"?

```
$("img.avatar").remove();
```

Comment: You can do `jQuery(document).off("mouseover mouseleave", "img.avatar")`

Comment: Since the avatars are dynamically created, couldn't they be added back later? You need to keep the delegations for that.

Comment: When you use delegation, there's just one listener attached to `document`, not a listener for each element. There's no memory leak.